# Limits of $(e^{xy}-1)/y$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

How would you solve this limit? It exists and is equal to 0 but I have no idea how to show it.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{e^{xy}-1}{y}$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Multiply by $1\color{grey}{=\dfrac x x}$.